# New error when knitting get_engine(options$engine)

Tags: r, knitr

I have an .Rmd file that previously had knitted without any problems.  Now I am getting the following error when executing this instruction

```
confusionMatrix(prediction1, ssTesting$classe)
```

The error is

```
Error in get_engine(options$engine) : Unknown language engine 'test' (must be registered via knit_engines$set())
```

If I execute each chunk independently the error does not occur.

It only happens if I `knit`.

The error is independent of using version R-3.1.2 or R-3.2.1.  I also set all the `cache options` to `FALSE` and made sure that all the libraries were correct but the error keeps appearing.

Answer (score 13):

A simple typo in the  beginning of the chunk ... ```` ```{rtest.mod1} ```` instead of ```` ```{r test.mod1} ````
Hard to see but simple to fix.